# Can a YAML document have more then one map, sequence or scalar as toplevel node?

Tags: yaml, snakeyaml

I wonder if a YAML document can have more then one map, sequence or scalar as top level node. Actually I thought not as I cannot imagine how such a document would look like. But after having a look the the source of SnakeYAML Engine it seems to be possible.

So, is it possible and can some one provide an example document?

Comment: No, it can't. "Toplevel" and "more than one" actually contradict each other. One document contains exactly one toplevel node. But a YAML file (or a stream) can contain more than one document.

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing it with YAML's ability to have multiple documents in a stream?

Comment: No, I only had a look at the implementation of SnakeYAML Engine. I was also supprised, since I also think that a document can have only one map, sequence, or scalar.